# Parsing float fails on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

When I try to parse string into float on real device it succeed , but fails on emulator. 
Both are on iOS 13.1. 
For example, "81,5" is converted into 81.5 on real device, but it converted into 815 on emulator

```
public static float StrToFloatDef(string value, float defValue)
{
      value = value.Replace('.', ',');

      float floatValue;

      if (float.TryParse(value.Trim(), out floatValue) == false)
           floatValue = defValue;

      return floatValue;
}
```

Comment: the decimal separator will vary depending on your locale.  Most likely your emulator and your device are not using the same locale settings

Answer (score 0):

You are right Jason.

I forced the comma as separator and now its working well

```
float.TryParse(value.Trim(), NumberStyles.Any, new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," }, out floatValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the two devices set to the same localization.
Some use period as the decimal separator, others use comma.

```
float.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```